# Extracting nested list in column of tibble to other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the ggmap package and I have created a tibble of 2 columns, an address and the output of geocode(address) in the 2nd column which is a nested list. I would like to extract information within this nested list into separate columns.

The tibble looks like this,

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
Origin                               geo         
<chr>                                <list>      
1 Major Arterial Road(South-East), De~ <named list~
2 Murari Pukur Govt Sponsored Higher ~ <named list~
3 Running Lab, RA Puram Trustpakkam M~ <named list~
4 Ravindra Bharathi, Saifabad Khairat~ <named list~
5 11/7, Adarsha Pally, Netaji Nagar, ~ <named list~
6 Hotel Eagle executive, Pimpri-Chinc~ <named list~
```

and the nest list contains the output of ggmap::geocode() which looks like (dput output)

```
list(results = list(list(address_components = list(list(long_name = "417", 
    short_name = "417", types = list("street_number")), list(
    long_name = "North Rawhide", short_name = "N Rawhide", types = list(
        "route")), list(long_name = "Mid-america Industrial Park", 
    short_name = "Mid-america Industrial Park", types = list(
        "neighborhood", "political")), list(long_name = "Olathe", 
    short_name = "Olathe", types = list("locality", "political")), 
    list(long_name = "Johnson County", short_name = "Johnson County", 
        types = list("administrative_area_level_2", "political")), 
    list(long_name = "Kansas", short_name = "KS", types = list(
        "administrative_area_level_1", "political")), list(long_name = "United States", 
        short_name = "US", types = list("country", "political")), 
    list(long_name = "66061", short_name = "66061", types = list(
        "postal_code")), list(long_name = "3657", short_name = "3657", 
        types = list("postal_code_suffix"))), formatted_address = "417 N Rawhide, Olathe, KS 66061, USA", 
    geometry = list(location = list(lat = 38.8861111, lng = -94.7913889), 
        location_type = "ROOFTOP", viewport = list(northeast = list(
            lat = 38.8874600802915, lng = -94.7900399197085), 
            southwest = list(lat = 38.8847621197085, lng = -94.7927378802915))), 
    place_id = "ChIJRVUJdB--wIcRHkCUc1X_XBk", plus_code = list(
        compound_code = "V6P5+CC Olathe, KS, USA", global_code = "86C7V6P5+CC"), 
    types = list("clothing_store", "establishment", "point_of_interest", 
        "shoe_store", "store"))), status = "OK")
```

My goal is to add additional columns to this tibble such as lat, long, county, country etc..

I have tried writing my own functions but they dont seem to work

What I tried was

```
get_lat <- function(geo) {
    return(geo$geometry$location$lat) 
}

MWE <- tibble(geo = lst) #(where lst is my dput output)
mutate(MWE, lat = map(geo, get_lat))
```

DPUT of head of tibble

```
structure(list(Origin = c("Major Arterial Road(South-East), Deshbandhu Nagar, New Town, West Bengal, India", 
"Murari Pukur Govt Sponsored Higher Secondary School, Ultadanga Main Road Ultadanga Kolkata West Bengal India", 
"Running Lab, RA Puram Trustpakkam Mandaveli Chennai Tamil Nadu India", 
"Ravindra Bharathi, Saifabad Khairatabad Hyderabad Telangana India", 
"11/7, Adarsha Pally, Netaji Nagar, Kolkata, West Bengal 700092, India", 
"Hotel Eagle executive, Pimpri-Chinchwad Maharashtra India"), 
    geo = list(list(results = list(list(address_components = list(
        list(long_name = "Major Arterial Road(South-East)", short_name = "Major Arterial Road(South-East)", 
            types = list("route")), list(long_name = "Deshbandhu Nagar", 
            short_name = "Deshbandhu Nagar", types = list("political", 
                "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2")), list(
            long_name = "New Town", short_name = "New Town", 
            types = list("locality", "political")), list(long_name = "North 24 Parganas", 
            short_name = "North 24 Parganas", types = list("administrative_area_level_2", 
                "political")), list(long_name = "West Bengal", 
            short_name = "WB", types = list("administrative_area_level_1", 
                "political")), list(long_name = "India", short_name = "IN", 
            types = list("country", "political"))), formatted_address = "Major Arterial Road(South-East), Deshbandhu Nagar, New Town, West Bengal, India", 
        geometry = list(bounds = list(northeast = list(lat = 22.6121767, 
            lng = 88.4750972), southwest = list(lat = 22.5835264, 
            lng = 88.4662183)), location = list(lat = 22.5977493, 
            lng = 88.4718048), location_type = "GEOMETRIC_CENTER", 
            viewport = list(northeast = list(lat = 22.6121767, 
                lng = 88.4750972), southwest = list(lat = 22.5835264, 
                lng = 88.4662183))), place_id = "Ek9NYWpvciBBcnRlcmlhbCBSb2FkKFNvdXRoLUVhc3QpLCBEZXNoYmFuZGh1IE5hZ2FyLCBOZXcgVG93biwgV2VzdCBCZW5nYWwsIEluZGlhIi4qLAoUChIJRdaq9U91AjoR7gvrdkF1FOASFAoSCb05qolEdQI6ETkXaZ56UBJJ", 
        types = list("route"))), status = "OK"), list(results = list(
        list(address_components = list(list(long_name = "Ultadanga Main Road", 
            short_name = "Ultadanga Main Rd", types = list("route")), 
            list(long_name = "Block-9", short_name = "Block-9", 
                types = list("neighborhood", "political")), list(
                long_name = "Murari Pukur", short_name = "Murari Pukur", 
                types = list("political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2")), 
            list(long_name = "Ultadanga", short_name = "Ultadanga", 
                types = list("political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1")), 
            list(long_name = "Kolkata", short_name = "Kolkata", 
                types = list("locality", "political")), list(
                long_name = "Kolkata", short_name = "Kolkata", 
                types = list("administrative_area_level_2", "political")), 
            list(long_name = "West Bengal", short_name = "WB", 
                types = list("administrative_area_level_1", "political")), 
            list(long_name = "India", short_name = "IN", types = list(
                "country", "political")), list(long_name = "700067", 
                short_name = "700067", types = list("postal_code"))), 
            formatted_address = "107 & 108/4, Ultadanga Main Rd, Block-9, Murari Pukur, Ultadanga, Kolkata, West Bengal 700067, India", 
            geometry = list(location = list(lat = 22.5923114, 
                lng = 88.3879988), location_type = "GEOMETRIC_CENTER", 
                viewport = list(northeast = list(lat = 22.5936603802915, 
                  lng = 88.3893477802915), southwest = list(lat = 22.5909624197085, 
                  lng = 88.3866498197085))), place_id = "ChIJRTqclBN2AjoRvFKeihU8Y6U", 
            plus_code = list(compound_code = "H9RQ+W5 Kolkata, West Bengal, India", 
                global_code = "7MJCH9RQ+W5"), types = list("establishment", 
                "point_of_interest", "school"))), status = "OK"), 
        list(results = list(list(address_components = list(list(
            long_name = "Chennai", short_name = "Chennai", types = list(
                "locality", "political")), list(long_name = "RA Puram", 
            short_name = "RA Puram", types = list("political", 
                "sublocality", "sublocality_level_3")), list(
            long_name = "Trustpakkam", short_name = "Trustpakkam", 
            types = list("political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2")), 
            list(long_name = "Mandaveli", short_name = "Mandaveli", 
                types = list("political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1")), 
            list(long_name = "Chennai", short_name = "Chennai", 
                types = list("administrative_area_level_2", "political")), 
            list(long_name = "Tamil Nadu", short_name = "TN", 
                types = list("administrative_area_level_1", "political")), 
            list(long_name = "India", short_name = "IN", types = list(
                "country", "political")), list(long_name = "600028", 
                short_name = "600028", types = list("postal_code"))), 
            formatted_address = "No 1, GF, Sai Durbar, 44/45, 2nd Main Road, Near Billroth Hospital, RA Puram, Trustpakkam, Mandaveli, RA Puram, Trustpakkam, Mandaveli, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600028, India", 
            geometry = list(location = list(lat = 13.0272203, 
                lng = 80.2568369), location_type = "GEOMETRIC_CENTER", 
                viewport = list(northeast = list(lat = 13.0285692802915, 
                  lng = 80.2581858802915), southwest = list(lat = 13.0258713197085, 
                  lng = 80.2554879197085))), place_id = "ChIJv0BOUshnUjoRZ4HdVwXArxA", 
            plus_code = list(compound_code = "27G4+VP Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India", 
                global_code = "7M5227G4+VP"), types = list("clothing_store", 
                "establishment", "point_of_interest", "store"))), 
            status = "OK"), list(results = list(list(address_components = list(
            list(long_name = "State Assembly", short_name = "State Assembly", 
                types = list("landmark")), list(long_name = "Lakdikapul Road", 
                short_name = "Lakdikapul Rd", types = list("route")), 
            list(long_name = "Saifabad", short_name = "Saifabad", 
                types = list("political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2")), 
            list(long_name = "Lakdikapul", short_name = "Lakdikapul", 
                types = list("political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1")), 
            list(long_name = "Hyderabad", short_name = "Hyderabad", 
                types = list("locality", "political")), list(
                long_name = "Hyderabad", short_name = "Hyderabad", 
                types = list("administrative_area_level_2", "political")), 
            list(long_name = "Telangana", short_name = "Telangana", 
                types = list("administrative_area_level_1", "political")), 
            list(long_name = "India", short_name = "IN", types = list(
                "country", "political")), list(long_name = "500004", 
                short_name = "500004", types = list("postal_code"))), 
            formatted_address = "Lakdikapul Rd, near State Assembly, Saifabad, Lakdikapul, Hyderabad, Telangana 500004, India", 
            geometry = list(location = list(lat = 17.4033074, 
                lng = 78.467095), location_type = "GEOMETRIC_CENTER", 
                viewport = list(northeast = list(lat = 17.4046563802915, 
                  lng = 78.4684439802915), southwest = list(lat = 17.4019584197085, 
                  lng = 78.4657460197085))), place_id = "ChIJ_33ft7mRMjoRMDstgG7X4N8", 
            plus_code = list(compound_code = "CF38+8R Hyderabad, Telangana, India", 
                global_code = "7J9WCF38+8R"), types = list("establishment", 
                "point_of_interest"))), status = "OK"), list(
            results = list(list(address_components = list(list(
                long_name = "11", short_name = "11", types = list(
                  "subpremise")), list(long_name = "7", short_name = "7", 
                types = list("premise")), list(long_name = "Adarsha Pally", 
                short_name = "Adarsha Pally", types = list("political", 
                  "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2")), list(
                long_name = "Netaji Nagar", short_name = "Netaji Nagar", 
                types = list("political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1")), 
                list(long_name = "Kolkata", short_name = "Kolkata", 
                  types = list("locality", "political")), list(
                  long_name = "Kolkata", short_name = "Kolkata", 
                  types = list("administrative_area_level_2", 
                    "political")), list(long_name = "West Bengal", 
                  short_name = "WB", types = list("administrative_area_level_1", 
                    "political")), list(long_name = "India", 
                  short_name = "IN", types = list("country", 
                    "political")), list(long_name = "700092", 
                  short_name = "700092", types = list("postal_code"))), 
                formatted_address = "11, 7, Adarsha Pally, Netaji Nagar, Kolkata, West Bengal 700092, India", 
                geometry = list(location = list(lat = 22.4814396, 
                  lng = 88.3604102), location_type = "ROOFTOP", 
                  viewport = list(northeast = list(lat = 22.4827885802915, 
                    lng = 88.3617591802915), southwest = list(
                    lat = 22.4800906197085, lng = 88.3590612197085))), 
                place_id = "EkYxMSwgNywgQWRhcnNoYSBQYWxseSwgTmV0YWppIE5hZ2FyLCBLb2xrYXRhLCBXZXN0IEJlbmdhbCA3MDAwOTIsIEluZGlhIh4aHAoWChQKEgkPR5DY4nACOhG1kq12opRwUxICMTE", 
                types = list("subpremise")), list(address_components = list(
                list(long_name = "11/7", short_name = "11/7", 
                  types = list("premise")), list(long_name = "Adarsha Pally", 
                  short_name = "Adarsha Pally", types = list(
                    "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2")), 
                list(long_name = "Netaji Nagar", short_name = "Netaji Nagar", 
                  types = list("political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1")), 
                list(long_name = "Kolkata", short_name = "Kolkata", 
                  types = list("locality", "political")), list(
                  long_name = "Kolkata", short_name = "Kolkata", 
                  types = list("administrative_area_level_2", 
                    "political")), list(long_name = "West Bengal", 
                  short_name = "WB", types = list("administrative_area_level_1", 
                    "political")), list(long_name = "India", 
                  short_name = "IN", types = list("country", 
                    "political")), list(long_name = "700092", 
                  short_name = "700092", types = list("postal_code"))), 
                formatted_address = "11/7, Adarsha Pally, Netaji Nagar, Kolkata, West Bengal 700092, India", 
                geometry = list(location = list(lat = 22.480674, 
                  lng = 88.363836), location_type = "ROOFTOP", 
                  viewport = list(northeast = list(lat = 22.4820229802915, 
                    lng = 88.3651849802915), southwest = list(
                    lat = 22.4793250197085, lng = 88.3624870197085))), 
                place_id = "ChIJ5fMASx1xAjoRymUCIwGCqYw", plus_code = list(
                  compound_code = "F9J7+7G Kolkata, West Bengal, India", 
                  global_code = "7MJCF9J7+7G"), types = list(
                  "street_address"))), status = "OK"), list(results = list(
            list(address_components = list(list(long_name = "251", 
                short_name = "251", types = list("street_number")), 
                list(long_name = "Pimpri-Chinchwad Link Road", 
                  short_name = "Pimpri-Chinchwad Link Rd", types = list(
                    "route")), list(long_name = "Gawade Nagar", 
                  short_name = "Gawade Nagar", types = list("political", 
                    "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2")), list(
                  long_name = "Chinchwad", short_name = "Chinchwad", 
                  types = list("political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1")), 
                list(long_name = "Pimpri-Chinchwad", short_name = "Pimpri-Chinchwad", 
                  types = list("locality", "political")), list(
                  long_name = "Pune", short_name = "Pune", types = list(
                    "administrative_area_level_2", "political")), 
                list(long_name = "Maharashtra", short_name = "MH", 
                  types = list("administrative_area_level_1", 
                    "political")), list(long_name = "India", 
                  short_name = "IN", types = list("country", 
                    "political")), list(long_name = "411033", 
                  short_name = "411033", types = list("postal_code"))), 
                formatted_address = "Survey No, 251, Pimpri-Chinchwad Link Rd, Gawade Nagar, Chinchwad, Pimpri-Chinchwad, Maharashtra 411033, India", 
                geometry = list(location = list(lat = 18.6301787, 
                  lng = 73.7938112), location_type = "ROOFTOP", 
                  viewport = list(northeast = list(lat = 18.6315276802915, 
                    lng = 73.7951601802915), southwest = list(
                    lat = 18.6288297197085, lng = 73.7924622197085))), 
                place_id = "ChIJbRla9GO5wjsR5gGzf6KGoJk", plus_code = list(
                  compound_code = "JQJV+3G Pimpri-Chinchwad, Maharashtra, India", 
                  global_code = "7JCMJQJV+3G"), types = list(
                  "establishment", "lodging", "point_of_interest"))), 
            status = "OK"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: hi @RonakShah I have updated the output to the output of dput(inner_list)

Comment: is inner_list an element of the geo column or what

Comment: the geo column contains many nested lists

Comment: can you `dput` the full `tibble`. because otherwise we can't help, for the issue is rising from the `get_lat` function.

Comment: Hi I have edited my original post with the dput output of the full tibble.

Comment: @mharinga 's answer is valid with the previous definition of get_lat. I submitted an edit to his answer showing the output and changing `map` to `map_dbl` the return value of `get_lat` is `geo$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat`

Comment: also I think you'll need both longitude and latitude so y not put the return value of get_lat (which now should be renamed to get_pos) to `geo$results[[1]]$geometry$location` and use the `tidyr::unnest_wider` to add both lat and long as columns i.e `tbl %>% mutate(pos = map(geo, get_lat))  %>% unnest_wider(col=pos)` this way you'll have your longitude and latitude in one go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example package purrr. Something like this should work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tbl %>% mutate(lat = map_dbl(geo, get_lat))
```

#### OUTPUT

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Origin                                                                                                       geo                lat
  <chr>                                                                                                        <list>           <dbl>
1 Major Arterial Road(South-East), Deshbandhu Nagar, New Town, West Bengal, India                              <named list [2]>  22.6
2 Murari Pukur Govt Sponsored Higher Secondary School, Ultadanga Main Road Ultadanga Kolkata West Bengal India <named list [2]>  22.6
3 Running Lab, RA Puram Trustpakkam Mandaveli Chennai Tamil Nadu India                                         <named list [2]>  13.0
4 Ravindra Bharathi, Saifabad Khairatabad Hyderabad Telangana India                                            <named list [2]>  17.4
5 11/7, Adarsha Pally, Netaji Nagar, Kolkata, West Bengal 700092, India                                        <named list [2]>  22.5
6 Hotel Eagle executive, Pimpri-Chinchwad Maharashtra India                                                    <named list [2]>  18.6
```

Comment: If I do that with my current get_lat function I get an error
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `lat`.
x $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
i Input `lat` is `map(geo, get_lat)`.

and the column fills up with the value from the first row.

Comment: Please add a MWE. I cannot reproduce your error. Your tibble is a list and not a data.frame.

Comment: the problem is the get_lat function as it gets the first element of the list which doesn't contain the wanted value. he should remove the `$results[[1]]` and it'll work

Comment: Fundamentally my goal is just to take that list under "dput output" and be able to extract components of that into different columns in my tibble. I've tried removing $results[[1]] but it doesn't work either. I still run into the same error as before.

I have updated what I tried on my original post.